# Query - Opportunities where last Stage change date is this calendar year

Tags: soql, query

I am struggling to get a query constructed to  Opportunities where last Stage change date is this calendar year.

```
SELECT Actual_Decision_Year_DE__c, Decision_Outcome_Details__c, Delegate_Days_del__c, Delegates__c, Event_Rating__c, Event_Year__c, Name, PrimaryReasonWon__c, Sector__c 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE ***Last Stage Change Date*** = THIS_YEAR AND StageName = 'Bid Won' AND Opportunity_Record_Type__c = 'Association' ORDER BY Event_Year__c ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a custom field that was specifically made to track this, `Opportunity` isn't the right object to base your query on...or rather not the only object to base your query on

`Opportunity`, by itself, can only give you information about the last time the record was changed (via `LastModifiedDate` or `SystemModStamp` for modifications originating by users or users/automated processes respectively). It can't tell you *what* field was changed.

Instead, you'll want to use the special history object that `Opportunity` has, `OpportunityHistory`

This object tracks changes to `StageName`, `Probability`, `Amount`, and `CloseDate`

To accomplish what you're trying to do, you'll probably end up using a semi-join. A semi-join is something of the form

`[SELECT <Fields> FROM <Object> WHERE Id IN (SELECT <Matching Id field> FROM <Related Object>)]`

A query inside of a query.

Combining everything together, your target query should look something like

`[SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityHistory WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR AND <other criteria here>)]`

Be aware that `OpportunityHistory` doesn't tell you *which* field was changed either. It's more of a snapshot of those select standard fields at a point in time when any one of them changed.

You may not be able to do this with a query alone. In which case you'd probably need to perform a parent-child subquery like `[SELECT Id, (SELECT StageName FROM OpportunityHistories ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC) FROM Opportunity WHERE <Criteria>]` and then iterate over the `OpportunityHistory` for each `Opportunity` to figure out exactly when the StageName was changed.

You could then store the `OpportunityId` in a collection if the `CreatedDate` matches your expectations.